# How to add and remove marker clusters on a leaflet map?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

I am using [leaflet market cluster](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster) and I am setting markers as circle markers.

> Leaflet version: leaflet@1.3.1
>
> Leaflet cluster version: markercluster@1.3.0

**NOTE**

> `$.fn.almDone...` and `$.fn.almEmpty...` are just some functions I use for
>   my ajax callbacks

I am drawing some markers on the map if we have results, and clear the markers we've drawn if on a second callback we have zero results. Or simply tell the user we've got zero results and therefore zero markers.

We have 2 arrays with values where I get the coordinates:

```
var longitude = [];
var latitude = [];
var count = [];
```

We set the var to `stopAjax true` when we start:

```
var stopAjax = true;
```

On click we start the search and we set `stopAjax` to `false`

```
$(".alm-filters--button").on("click", function(){
  stopAjax = false;
});
```

And that is the basic logic, now we define two functions:

```
// This is run when we finish the call and we have results
// So on the callback we run the function to draw the markers

$.fn.almDone = function(alm){
  drawMarkers();
};

// Let's draw the markers

function drawMarkers() {

  // This is the logic to read latitude and longitude arrays
  // and push to a new array the two values as pair of coords
  // eg. 4.66, 4,5555 

  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < longitude.length; ++i) {
    pair=[ parseFloat( latitude[i] ) , parseFloat(  longitude[i]  ) ]
    count.push(  pair );
    $("#searchNations").removeAttr("disabled");
    $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
    var myYears = $('#years').val();
    $("#ajax-load-more ul").attr("data-meta-value", myYears);
  };

  // We check if we said to run ajax
  // and if so draw the markers
  // for myself I had also to retrieve those coords
  // and place them in individual inputs for the form

  if(stopAjax == false) {
    L.MarkerCluster.include({
      spiderfy: function(e) {
        var childMarkers = this.getAllChildMarkers();
        this._group._unspiderfy();
        this._group._spiderfied = this;

        // Fill the markersList.

        markersList.innerHTML = childMarkers
        .map((marker, index) => `<li>Marker ${index + 1}: ${marker.getLatLng()}</li>`)
        .join('');

        // If there are any childMarkers
        // draw the cluster and run a form

        if(childMarkers.length > 0) {
          // Match the lat and lng numbers from the string returned by getLatLng()
          const [lat, lng] = `${ childMarkers[0].getLatLng() }`.match(/(-?\d+.\d*)/gi);  

          // Construct the required string value from the extracted numbers
          const requiredString = `${ lat }, ${ lng }`;

          // Use requiredString to populate the value attribute of the input field in OP

          // grab the coords in individual inputs
          // that's just for my specific case

          $("#longiTude").attr("value",lat);
          $("#latiTude").attr("value", lng); 

          // run a form to see results

          submitSearchForm();
        }
      },
      unspiderfy: function() {
        this._group._spiderfied = null;
      }
    });

    // this bit is for single marker
    // we want to add a click to run the form 
    // also for the single marker and grab the coords 
    // and place them in inputs for the form

    var mcg = L.markerClusterGroup().addTo(map);

    circles = new L.MarkerClusterGroup();
    for (var i = 0; i < count.length; i++) {
      var a = count[i];
      var circle = new L.CircleMarker([a[0], a[1]]);
      circles.addLayer(circle);
      circle.on('click', function (e) {
        var curPos = e.target.getLatLng();
        $("#longiTude").val(curPos.lat);
        $("#latiTude").val(curPos.lng);
        submitSearchForm();
      });
    }

    // we add the markers to the map
    map.addLayer(circles);

    // we empty the arrays for the future calls

    count = [];
    longitude = [];

    // we set again stopAjax var to true to reset
    stopAjax = true;   
  }
}
```

Then the zero results function

```
//This is run when we have zero results

$.fn.almEmpty = function(alm) {
 stopAjax = true;
  clearMarkers();
};

// We empty the arrays and we
// clear the previously drawn markers

function clearMarkers(stopAjax) {
  if(stopAjax == true) {
    count = [];
    longitude = [];
    map.removeLayer(circles);
  }
  // if zero results, we launch a modal to advise user
  $('#zeroResults').modal('show');
}
```

The above works if We first have results and then we do another search and we have zero results, but in case we've made a search at first and we've got `zero results`, then we will have an error:

> ```
> Uncaught ReferenceError: circles is not defined
> ```

And that's correct because since we get into the `empty function` we try to `clear the markers` which we haven't ever defined as we never got into the draw markers function where we define `circles`.

I am getting very confused on how to draw the markers and make the `var circles` available in both cases.

> p.s. Happy for anyone to improve the logic regardless of the question issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would consider putting `circles` as a variable outside the scope of either function via `var circles = undefined;`. Note that the problem isn't that circles is `undefined` but that it is not defined, i.e not recognised as a variable.

Then set it as you do in `drawMarkers`.

On clearMarkers before the call to removeLayer check `if (circles)` to check that it is defined.
Then set it to undefined again after calling removeLayer.